# Trouble with CheckBox matrix, loops won't work

Tags: java, loops, checkbox, nested

I am writing a program which will have multiple windows that will pass a value between them. 
Currently I am testing one part of my program that is made out of 1-99 checkboxes. But when I want to check their states by clicking on a button it just doesn't work. Here's where the problem is:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {



    if(event.getSource() == okay) {
        for(int i=0;i<box.length; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<box.length; j++){
                if((i==0)&&(j==0)) continue;                    
                if(box[i][j].getState())
                asdf.matra[i][j]=true;
                System.out.println(box[i][j].getLabel() + " is " + asdf.matra[i][j]);
                }       
        }

    }


}
```

here's the main class:

```
    public class asdf {
    public static boolean matra[][] = new boolean[10][10];

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

    for(int ii=0;ii<matra.length; ii++){
        for(int jj=0;jj<matra.length; jj++){
            matra[ii][jj]=false;
            }           
    }
    new JFrameDemo();
}
}
```

and the other class:

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

public class JFrameDemo extends Frame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {
    Checkbox box[][] = new Checkbox[10][10];
    Button okay;



JFrameDemo() {
    enableEvents(AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
    add(makePanel());
    pack();
    show();

}
private Panel makePanel() {


    GridBagConstraints con = new GridBagConstraints();
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout();
    panel.setLayout(gridbag);

    for(int i=0;i<box.length; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<box.length; j++){
            if((i==0)&&(j==0)) continue;                    

            box[i][j] = new Checkbox(i+j*10+"");
            con.gridx = i;
            con.gridy = j;
            panel.add(box[i][j],con);
            }           
    }

    okay = new Button("Unesi");
    con.gridx = 10;
    con.gridy = 10;
    panel.add(okay,con);

    return(panel);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource() == okay) {
        for(int i=0;i<box.length; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<box.length; j++){
                if((i==0)&&(j==0)) continue;                    
                if(box[i][j].getState())
                asdf.matra[i][j]=true;
                System.out.println(box[i][j].getLabel() + " is " + asdf.matra[i][j]);
                }       
        }

    }


}
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {

}
public void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent event) {
    if(event.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)
        System.exit(0);
}
}
```

The program is running without any errors, but the console isn't giving any results. It is supposed to pass value to the global variable also. I think there's an issues with nested fors.

Comment: And which part of your code is having problem? Of course you don't want us to skim through your whole code right?

Comment: It's there actually, it's the first code segment I've put. Fors seem not to work, I've tried with a Checkbox array and it does work, I initiate the checkbox matrix, but when I am supposed to click on okay button and check their states, go trough them all with fors it just doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to add the ActionListener to the button.

```
okay = new Button("Unesi");
okay.addActionListener(this);
```